# How do I check if an environment variable is set in cmake

Tags: bash, cmake, environment-variables

I set an environment variable in my bash profile, so I can see it in the terminal just fine . .

> blah/builds$ echo $THING
>
> thingy

How do I display it in a cmake message and check if it is set? I have tried the following, but it just displays thing as blank and skips the body of the if statement

```
message("THING:" $ENV{THING})
if(DEFINED ENV{THING})
    message(STATUS "THING environment variable defined")
    # some more commands
endif()
```

Comment: Is that variable `export`ed in the shell? What does `declare -p THING` say? Does running `export THING` before running `cmake` help?

Comment: It works fine if hardcoding to known env variable => message("THING:" $ENV{PATH}) prints the path, seems the typical problem with strings

Comment: Actually it works fine in Win7, I set THING=thingy in the console, then the scripts output what is expected. CMake 3.2.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You CMake code is correct. The problem is most likely that you only *set* the environment variable in your shell but did not *export* it. Run the following before invoking `cmake`:

```
export THING
```

Answer (score 54):

Knowing perfectly well what `export` does and how environment works in general, I've still got a mouthful of WTFs with this form:

```
IF(DEFINED $ENV{THING})
```

but it worked fine in this form:

```
IF(DEFINED ENV{THING})
```

**Notice the `$` omission.**

---

N.B. you can quickly test this using `cmake -P`:

```
[~] cat > test-env.cmake << 'EOF'
IF(DEFINED ENV{FOOBAR})
    MESSAGE(STATUS "FOOBAR env seen: --[$ENV{FOOBAR}]--")
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(STATUS "WTF")
ENDIF()
EOF
[~]
[~] FOOBAR=test cmake -P test-env.cmake
-- FOOBAR env seen: --[test]--
```

---

The reason it behaves so weirdly, is legacy, as usual. `IF` used to do insane stuff in older CMake; they sort-of fixed this in CMake 3.1 — in a backward-compatible manner — with [CMP0054](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/policy/CMP0054.html), which you have to enable explicitly:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.1)
PROJECT(...)

CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0054 NEW) #-- fixes IF() with quoted args
CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0057 NEW) #-- enables IF(.. IN_LIST ..)
```

Comment: Can I recommend - can you change your answer so that first would be correct answer, and later on incorrect. Because normally you just copy answer, and then you notice it did not work out.

Comment: @TarmoPikaro let me respectfully decline. If you ask me, I normally **read** answers and code within, and never directly copy-paste code (because that's seriously bad engineering). You're supposed to pay attention to what you read. You're supposed to be able to *type out four words* on your own.

Comment: @ulidtko while you do make sense, I also fell victim of copy paste :)

Answer (score 14):

Just to be clear: as https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html says:

```
if (DEFINED ENV{THING})
  # do stuff
endif()
```

is the right syntax, no $ anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

I did this but it doesn't work. CMake can't detect it.

```
export THING
```

But this one is works.

```
export THING=on
```

Maybe I should always give default value for environment variable.

By the way, you can check the environment string by following CMake code.

```
if( $ENV{THING} STREQUAL "on")
    message(STATUS "THING = " $ENV{THING})
endif()
```

Comment: Should be `ENV{}` not `$ENV{}`.

Answer (score -13):

Replace

```
if(DEFINED ENV{THING})
```

with

```
if(DEFINED $ENV{THING})
```

You missed a '$' before the variable.

Comment: This is not true: [the `if` command evaluates its arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/if.html)

Comment: This answer is incorrect; however, it lead me to try `IF(DEFINED ENV{THING})` without the `$` **and this actually worked**. Paradoxically, this answer came as the single helpful answer in the whole thread.